# overiding processKeyEvent in Java

Tags: java, jtextarea, overriding

I am developing an application that will support Arabic Text in it. I am not using system level language in it. User just have to press the Key, and according to that key, Arabic unicode will be inserted in JTextArea. I've created a class ArabicTextArea and made it extended with Swing's JTextArea. I included a override function processKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) in this class. Now my problem is that, whenever I press some key, this function triggers 3 times, may be 1st time for KeyDown, 2nd time for KeyUp and 3rd time for KeyPressed. I want that this function trigger only once, but I don't know how. Please someone help me...

I am using following code

```
@Override
protected void processKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    switch (event.getKeyChar()) {
    case 'a':
        append("\u0627");
        break;
    case 'H':
        append("\u062D");
        break;
    case 'm':
        append("\u0645");
        break;
    case 'd':
        append("\u062F");
        break;
    default:
        super.processKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is being called multiple times because 3 events occur ('a' for example):

- KEY_PRESSED, keyCode=65, keyChar='a'
- KEY_TYPED keyCode=0, keyChar='a'
- KEY_RELEASED, keyCode=65, keyChar='a'

and the code above only distinguishes by the KeyChar.  Use

```
event.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED
```

to ignore the press and release events, since you only care if the user typed the character.